# Android : TYPE_CLASS_PHONE keypad issue

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to show a kepyad only with following numbers and characters:
`*0123456789#` , but when I am using

```
accessCodeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

I have some another characters like `+WNP()/-,.` , how can I hide this extra characters from keypad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your EditText in xml file to:

```
<EditText
    .
    .
    .
android:inputType="phone" />
```

Comment: It's equivalent with accessCodeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);

Comment: but for me has not extra character!, test your app on other devices, i think this issue is dependent on the default keyboard that user selected in the device setting.